# Does the rectangle contain the point?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

A rectangle is defined by the 4 points ABCD. How can I tell if a given point, (x,y), is in the interior of the rectangle?

My current guess is the following:

- To be inside the rectangle, the point should be between the lines AB and CD, and between the lines AD and BC.
- The equation of line AB (and, similarly, the other lines) can be written as:

$$ \frac{x-x_A}{y-y_A} = \frac{x_B-x_A}{y_B-y_A} $$

- In order to be between line AB and line CD, one of the following must hold:

Either:

$$ \frac{x-x_A}{y-y_A} > \frac{x_B-x_A}{y_B-y_A} and \frac{x-x_D}{y-y_D} < \frac{x_C-x_D}{y_C-y_D}  $$

Or vice versa:

$$ \frac{x-x_A}{y-y_A} < \frac{x_B-x_A}{y_B-y_A} and \frac{x-x_D}{y-y_D} > \frac{x_C-x_D}{y_C-y_D}  $$

(According to the actual values of A, B, C and D, some of these conditions may be impossible or trivial).

- In order to be between line AD and BC, one of the following must hold:

Either:

$$ \frac{x-x_A}{y-y_A} > \frac{x_D-x_A}{y_D-y_A} and \frac{x-x_B}{y-y_B} < \frac{x_C-x_B}{y_C-y_B}  $$

Or vice versa:

$$ \frac{x-x_A}{y-y_A} < \frac{x_D-x_A}{y_D-y_A} and \frac{x-x_B}{y-y_B} > \frac{x_C-x_B}{y_C-y_B}  $$

Is this correct? Is there an easier way to calculate if a point is inside a square?

Comment: Perhaps Computational Geometry may help you to solve more complex queries of this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $ABCD$ are in cyclic order around the rectangle, if $P$ is your point, consider the points as vectors.  You want $(A-B)\cdot P$ to be between $(A-B) \cdot A$ and $(A-B) \cdot B$
and $(A-D) \cdot P$ to be between $(A-D)\cdot A$ and $(A-D) \cdot D$.

Comment: I fail to see the geometry behind this solution. AFAIU, (A-B) is a vector that points from B to A, and P is a vector that points from the origin to P. What is the geometric meaning of their dot product?

Comment: My condition says that the component of $P$ in the direction of each of the axes of the rectangle is between the two values of that component on the vertices of the rectangle.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you mean "quadrilateral", not rectangle (i.e. a polygon with 4 sides).

If so, then this is the classical "point in polygon" problem. There are two ways to attack it -- one way is to use ray casting, counting crossings, and the other is to use winding numbers.

You'll find lots of other material if you search for "point in polygon". [Here is one link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon), and  [here is another one](http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/).

Comment: Thank you for the links, but you refer to algorithmic solutions, and I am looking for a closed-form formula, that I can use in theoretic proofs.

Comment: Will the "winding number" function work, then?

Comment: I found several definitions of the winding number: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number but I am not sure how to apply them to a simple rectangle. Needs more thought.

Comment: The ray-crossing method is also a possible solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I found several definitions of the winding numer: [Wikipedia:Winding_number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) but I am not sure how to apply them to a simple rectangle.

Consider the rectangle as a closed curve $C$, then apply equations from the section **Differential geometry** and **Complex analysis** in the Wikipedia article:

- in a real plane XY:
  $$\text{winding number} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_C \,\frac{x}{r^2}\,dy - \frac{y}{r^2}
  \,dx$$
- in a complex plane Z:
  $$\text{winding number} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{dz}{z}$$